# Scan Documents from Scanner and store directly into Sharepoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've been asked to create a button called "Scan". When this button is clicked, it will start scanning the file in the Scanner machine and then storing the file in the library. However, I've searched throughout many websites and I found out that there must be a third-party to do that. Is there any scanning service or some script that can be integrated to perform this task?

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the scanner it may be able to send scans as emails either directly or through an app.

If that's the case then you can [email enable the document library](http://sharepointquester.com/2013/09/04/configuring-incoming-email-on-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library/) and then configure the scanner to send to the email address of the document library.

Comment: You can also address the library directly via WebDAV, same as Explorer View address.

Comment: What do you mean please explorer further please

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, in my opinion, the best thing I've come across to scan directly into sharepoint or office 365 was using a product called GScan Online. It literally does more than just the scanning, it has great imaging feature, OCR to index info directly into the metadata fields, and even provides a fulltext searchable pdf. You can even try it out for a month for free, and see if you like it, but it's the easiest App I've used in order to scan directly within sharepoint, and I never have to leave my sharepoint window/environment.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Per Jakobsen and wish to add that there also intelligent scanners (I have seen such models from HP) that even have the required button on the scanner's menu and are capable of scanning and doing OCR before sending the document to the designated document library.

Answer (score 2):

I have to add my support to the **original** request...

Here's the scenario: a user has used their browser to get to a specific Sharepoint site/library.  They realize that they have in hand the printed copy of the document that they need in this library to which they have browsed.  Why can't they press a button in the ribbon that is labeled **Scan** that fires-up their scanner and saves the scan in the library to which they have browsed?

Why do they need to send it to Email, get a workflow to run, etc?

What would be even better would be to modify the Upload "dialog" that appears when you click the ribbon **Upload Document** button to have a *start-the-scanner* option.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Udocx for SharePoint](http://www.udocx.com/SharePoint). It'll allow you to browse SharePoint from the scanner/MFP and both print from and scan to specific folders.

Answer (score 1):

[Asprise Web Scan](http://asprise.com/webscan/) has a browser extension (Chrome & Firefox) that adds a scan button beside the 'Upload' button in Sharepoint:

[image]

Click 'Scan' to start scanning from any TWAIN scanners.

Disclaimer: I am from the developer company.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this, you can use the `One Drive Scan` option to sync the contents of a particular folder, in your case, the directory where the scanned documents are saved. And once the scanned document is synced to the SharePoint, you can create a flow to make the content of the file uploaded to be searchable. I had gone through two ways to this requirement.

**Using Azure Form Recognizer, Without any third party tools**

To achieve this, you will have to create the flow as in the preceding image.

[image]

[Here is an article](https://sibeeshpassion.com/azure-form-recognizer-and-microsoft-flow-to-search-scanned-pdf-content-in-sharepoint-online/) with a full explanation and steps.

**Using a third-party tool**

Here I was using a tool called AquaFores in the Flow, and full steps are given in the image below.

[image]

[Here is the article](https://sibeeshpassion.com/search-contents-of-a-pdf-file-in-sharepoint-online-make-them-searchable-using-microsoft-flow/) with a full explanation.